# System.out.println() in jsp declaration tag

Tags: java, jsp

Why we cant use System.out.println(); inside the jsp **declaration** element?
When i am trying to write that line,compiler error displayed.

```
<%!System.out.println("test") %> 
 <body> 
  <form action="FindPhone" method="post"> 
    PhoneNumber : <input type="text" name="phone"> 
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
 </form>
```

Comment: Show some code please or we can't help

Comment: sorry i cant write system.out.println() into **declaration element** in jsp                                                                     **<%!System.out.println("test") %>**
<body>
<form action="FindPhone" method="post"> 
PhoneNumber : <input type="text" name="phone">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

Comment: redelman431 last week i attend interview they are asked me this question, so i'm trying here

Answer (score 0):

Because the declaration element translates to a field declaration in the class generated by the JSP:

```
public class GeneratedJsp extends JspServlet {

    System.out.println("test");

}
```

is not valid Java code. A declaration element is supposed to contain... a declaration.